# read byte by byte from memory without system call or a library function in C

Tags: c, memory, assembly, byte

I want to move information byte by byte from one memory location to another without using any library function. Am using a 16bits architecture emulated in qemu and this code is part of tiny small kernel i am writing, so i can not use any system call

```
// The struct i want to copy
struct procinfo info_tmp;
// here i put some stuff in my struct    
info_tmp.pid = tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].pid;
kstrcpy(info_tmp.nombre, tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].nombre);  
info_tmp.segmento = tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].memoria;
if(tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].estado==PROCESO_LISTO)
  info_tmp.estado = 0;
else if(tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].estado==PROCESO_RUN)
  info_tmp.estado = 1;
else if(tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].estado==BLOQ_TECLADO ||
tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].estado==PROCESO_SYSCALL)
  info_tmp.estado = 2;
else
  info_tmp.estado = 3; // Zombie
// Tiempo total = tiempoSYS + tiempoUSER
info_tmp.tiempo = tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].tiempoUSER +
  tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].tiempoSYS;    

// pointer to destination that i want to copy to
infoProc = (struct procinfo *)(((int)es << 16) + (0x0000ffff & ebx));
// now pointer to my source struct  
procinfo * origen = &info_tmp;         
int limit = sizeof(struct procinfo);
int i;
for(i=0;i<limit;i++){  
   //  I need here to read only one byte from my source pointer to a variable "byte"

   // macro written in ASM to copy one byte to a pointed location
   // it writes in another data segment of another process
   WRITE_POINTER_FAR(infoProc,byte);
   // next byte
   origen += 1; 
   infoProc += 1;
}
```

Is there a direct way to do it without the need to write a small code in ASM to do it manually ?

Note: This code is part of a 16bits segmented OS kernel (a 64KB segment for each process), the source struct is in the kernel segment and i want to copy it to a location in another process segment and it can not be like *targetBytePointer = *sourceBytePointer.

Comment: Why doesn't *targetBytePointer = *sourceBytePointer; work? I must be missing something in what you are asking...

Comment: 1) stylistic: `else if ... else if ...` : consider a swith construct, that will remove a lot of visual clutter. 2) `origen + 0x1;` statement has no meaning 3) why the hex constants for 1 ?

Comment: It is a 16bits segmented OS kernel (a segment for each process), what you see is in the kernel segment and i want to copy it to a location in another process segment and it can not be done as you suggest

Comment: wildplasser, by origen + 0x1; i pretend to sum one to my pointer to my source struct, meaning pointing next byte in my source (the hex constant is for nothing, just one)

Comment: Travis Griggs , this code is part of a 16bits segmented OS kernel (a 64KB segment for each process), the source struct is in the kernel segment and i want to copy it to a location in another process segment and it can not be like *targetBytePointer = *sourceBytePointer.

Comment: @YoussefKhloufi- `origen + 0x1` does not move your pointer as you expect.  It calculates the address of the next byte, but nothing is actually done with that value.  You need an assignment statement if you want to actually update the pointer.  Try `origen = origen + 0x1` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// The struct i want to copy
struct procinfo info_tmp;
// here i put some stuff in my struct    
info_tmp.pid = tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].pid;
kstrcpy(info_tmp.nombre, tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].nombre);  
info_tmp.segmento = tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].memoria;

switch(tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].estado) {
case PROCESO_LISTO:
  info_tmp.estado = 0; break;
case PROCESO_RUN:
  info_tmp.estado = 1; break;
case BLOQ_TECLADO :
case PROCESO_SYSCALL:
  info_tmp.estado = 2; break;
default:
  info_tmp.estado = 3; // Zombie
        break;
        }
// Tiempo total = tiempoSYS + tiempoUSER
info_tmp.tiempo = tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].tiempoUSER +
  tablaprocesos[indiceProceso].tiempoSYS;

// pointer to destination that i want to copy to
infoProc = (struct procinfo *)(((int)es << 16) + (0x0000ffff & ebx));
char *dest = (char*) infoProc;
// now pointer to my source struct  
char * origen = (char*) &info_tmp;
int limit = sizeof(struct procinfo);
int i;
for(i=0;i<limit;i++){ 
   char byte;
   //  I need here to read only one byte from my source pointer to a variable "byte"

   // macro written in ASM to copy one byte to a pointed location
   // it writes in another data segment of another process
   byte = *origen;
   WRITE_POINTER_FAR(dest,byte);
   // next byte
   origen += 1;
   dest += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally wrote a small ASM code to do it manually. I had to, because as i noted before it is a fragment of code of a 16bits kernel i am writing and emulating in qemu and that does memory segmentation (64KB for each process and 10 processes total). I can not do `*targetBytePointer = *sourceBytePointer` as targetPointer is in the process segment and sourcePointer is in the kernel segment and that is why i have the macro WRITE_POINTER_FAR for. Basically WRITE_POINTER_FAR (written is ASM) will use the destination pointer that i already created combining what the calling process passed to me in two registers (ES:BX), and will write only one byte to that destination and that's why i needed to read only one byte from my source each time.

```
char byte;
struct procinfo * origen = &info_tmp;  
for(i=0;i<limit;i++){
  asm( // leer un byte
    "mov %1,%%ebx   \n\t"
    "mov (%%ebx),%0  \n\t"
    :"=r"(byte)
    :"r"(origen)
  );
  WRITE_POINTER_FAR(infoProc,byte);
  origen += 1;
  infoProc += 1;
}
```

Edit: another simple solution

```
char *byte;
struct procinfo * origen = &info_tmp;  
for(i=0;i<limit;i++){     
  byte = (char*)origen;
  WRITE_POINTER_FAR(infoProc,*byte);
  origen += 1;
  infoProc += 1;
}
// actualizar puntero de proceso
if(indiceProceso+1<=MAX_PROCESOS)
  indiceProceso++;
return 0;
```

Comment: You do it again: `origen + 0x1;
infoProc + 0x1;` these statements **do nothing**! Do you want to increment the two pointers? : use `origen += 1; infoproc +=1;` (or `origin++;` etc)

Comment: Your *byte pointer is set to the beginning of origin at each interation of the loop; the increment at the end us still useless. See my answer. You also need to add some semicolons.

Comment: I don't see the problem  as i already changed the increment as you suggested : ` origen += 1; infoproc +=1; `

Comment: The origen and infoproc pointers do not have charater granularity. Incrementing them means: incrementing the addresses by sizeof (struct procinfo)

Comment: Using `%ebx` in 16-bit code?  Erm... someone's a bit confused.  EBX is 32 bits.

Comment: @cHao, i know it is a 32 bits register, but it is my tiny kernel that is 16bits while am still using my VM in qemu as 32bits machine. I am doing it just for learning how an old operating system work using a FAT12 files system, 10 fixed memory segments (partitions) for 10 processes, COM executables, Round Robbin process planification...etc

Comment: @Yousef: I conclude that your thinking is troubled by an ASM background. That should not be problem, but you really have to know about pointer arithmatic in C. (it is very simple; but different) Also: in C you have a choice of constructs: switch vs chained if...else (or even goto ...) , for(;;){} vs while{}, etc. Choose the clearest one; the one that is compact and easy to read. BTW: my initial comment is two hours old now. You effectively wasted two hours by not reading it.

Comment: Thank you very much, i used to code in java and that's why i see C pointers a bit different.